# how does an Activity communicate with a ListFragment in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity that extends `ActionBarActivity`. This activity displays data using a `ListFragment`. In this activity, when a user clicks on a `MenuItem`, I want to do a HTTP call in the background to fetch some data, after which, I need to update the `ListFragment`. I need to know how to update the `ListFragment` from the activity.

The layout XML is defined as follows (snippet).

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
    <fragment android:id="@+id/browse class="x.y.z.CustomListFragment"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The activity's Java code looks like the following.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.browser);
}

@Override
protected boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    MenuItem miActionSearch = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)miActionSearch.getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(R.id.refresh == item.getItemId()) {
        //logic to fetch data and refresh ListFragment goes here
    }
}
```

The ListFragment's code looks like the following.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
 setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
 super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
 //do i need to inflate here again?
 //inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
 if(R.id.refresh == item.getItemId()) {
  //do asynchronous data fetching task here
 }
}
```

I read an SO post that said to let the `ListFragment` handle the menu items being clicked, but when I override `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem)` inside the `ListFragment`, it seems that does not work; I placed a break point inside that method which is never reached.

I am sure this is a commonly recurring problem in Android, and would like to know how to resolve this problem and what design patterns, if any, are there documented on interacting with Fragments.

Just to clarify, I'm using the Android support `ListFragment` at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ListFragment.html. There is another `ListFragment` at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html, which I am NOT using.

Any help is appreciated.

Here's the solution that worked for me.

- remove from the `ActionBarActivity` the method override `onCreateOptionsMenu`
- remove from the `ActionBarActivity` the method override `onOptionsItemSelected`

Then inside the `ListFragment` do the following.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
 setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
 super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
 inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
 //any additional code here, like setting up the searching feature
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
 if(R.id.refresh == item.getItemId()) { 
  //... logic
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement `onActivityCreated()` in the `Fragment` and call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` from there. Then override `onCreateOptionsMenu(MenuInflater, Menu)` in the `Fragment`. And remember `onCreateOptionsMenu` returns a boolean when implemented in an `Activity` but returns void when implemented in a `Fragment`

Comment: I've revised the code per your suggestion but it still doesn't work. A few questions. 1) Where do I inflate the menu? In the `Activity` or in the `ListFragment`? 2) If the `Activity` and `ListFragment` both override `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`, do both methods get called? Ideally, I only want the `ListFragment` to handle all the code (not the `Activity`).

Comment: Nevermind, thanks, I tinkered a bit per your suggestion and got it to work. Hopefully the snippet above will help clarify for others too.

Comment: @JaneWayne: 1) Inflate the menu you want to show for your `ListFragment`  in the `ListFragment`. 2) If `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is implemented in the `Activity` as well as the `ListFragment` then the `MenuItem`s of both the `Menu`s are shown together ie the `MenuItem`s of the `ListFragment` are added to the `MenuItem`s of the `Activity`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to call `super.onOptionsItemSelected` from your Activity and then that method will be executed on your Fragment and you can do all the network stuff from the Fragment.

hiphopdroid explains how you can also create the options menu from within the Fragment. Depending on your application that may be more modular.

Comment: Is `super.onOptionsItemSelected` the last thing I do inside the override of `onOptionsItemSelected`? When trying the approach suggested by you, only the `Activity`'s `onOptionsItemSelected` gets triggered (and NOT the `ListFragment`).

Comment: Just to clarify it doesn't matter whether you inflate the menu in the Activity or in the Fragment, both can still respond to menu items. If you're overriding onOptionsItemSelected in the Activity then you must call the super method for the corresponding Fragment method to be executed. The part that must have been missing from my answer was to call setHasOptionsMenu in the Fragment, I didn't think this was necessary because you were inflating the menu in the Activity and not in the Fragment. You have it working well doing everything in the Fragment anyway.